# Creating a common audit column in EF6 with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an existing database that has auditing on some tables with effectively temporal table functionality behind them (records get timestamped when changed and previous versions are stored in a history table, this is taken care by SQL and not EF/app logic).

There is a TPC Table-Per-Concrete-Class inheritance model being used.  I have simplified the problem in the code below (Console app that will create a db called EfAudit on local).

Table Supplier already has an audit column on it, called ChangedBy, which works perfectly.

But Supplier is a specialised type of Organisation, normally Organisation is sufficient to store all the information required for an organisation - hence it not being marked as abstract.

I now need to record when the Organisations table has been updated with a ChangedBy field.  But when I add it to the model/ef only the underlying Organisations table is ever updated.

I know with EFCore you can use Shadow Properties to do similar work, but this system is built on Framework and not Core and switching isn't feasible.

I have tried setting the CurrentValues for the column explicitly on each entity, but only the base table ever has the value written to it.  I've tried blocking the base class in C# with the new keyword.  I cannot find out *how* I achieve this with EF6.

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EfAuditTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context cxt = new Context();

            cxt.Suppliers.Add(new Supplier()        // Some test data
            {
                Name = "Acme Inc",
                ContractStart = DateTime.Now,
            });

            cxt.Organisations.Add(new Organisation()    // A generic organisation that isn't a supplier
            {
                Name = "Just a business"
            });

            cxt.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    #region Model

    interface IAudit        // An auditing interface applicable to most database tables
    {
        string ChangedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Base      // Common table stuff
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Organisation : Base, IAudit        // An organisation, concrete as sometimes has everything needed
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ChangedBy { get; set; } = "Application User 42";
    }

    public class Supplier : Organisation        // A specialised organsiation that extends with some extra fields
    {
        public DateTime ContractStart { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Schema

    public class OrganisationSchema : EntityTypeConfiguration<Organisation>
    {
        public OrganisationSchema()
        {
            Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("Organisations");
            });

            HasKey(m => m.Id)
                .Property(m => m.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            /* THIS BIT HERE
             * If I add this to the Organisation table, it stops working in the Supplier table. */
            Property(p => p.ChangedBy);
        }
    }

    public class SupplierSchema : EntityTypeConfiguration<Supplier>
    {
        public SupplierSchema()
        {
            Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("Suppliers");
            });

            /* THIS BIT HERE
             * This mapping is now ignored by EF, and only the one in OrgansiationSchema is updated on writes */
            Property(p => p.ChangedBy);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Context

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrganisationSchema());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SupplierSchema());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public Context() : base("Server=(local);Database=EfAudit;Integrated Security=SSPI")
        {

        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Many thanks for any answers!

Comment: So is the problem that both the Organization table and Supplier table now have a ChangedBy column and only Organization's ChangedBy column is being updated?

Comment: Exactly.  It makes sense from a POCO perspective as Supplier is a type, there is only one ChangedBy record.  But from a database record perspective that object is split in a normalised fashion.  I can't see how to marry up the two concepts.

Comment: While also not perfect, Table-per-hierarchy has many advantages.  This is one.